# activar entornos virtuales respaldados

Tags: python, virtualenv

disculpen, le di formato a mi equipo y respalde la carpeta envs, ahora, como puedo utilizar esa carpeta de respaldo, que tengo que hacer para que de nuevo pueda trabajar en esos entornos virtuales que respalde?? Gracias.

Comment: En principio debería bastar con que "actives" el entorno, ejecutando el script dentro del mismo. Si quieres, puedes también copiarlos de tu copia de respaldo al lugar donde estaban antes. No obstante, es posible que (dependiendo de tu operativo) los entornos virtuales contuvieran enlaces simbólicos hacia otras carpetas donde está (estaba) el python que los creó, y sus paquetes. En ese caso quizás tu copia de respaldo no tenga los enlaces y no funcoine. Y en todo caso deberías tener instalado también el python con que los creaste.

Comment: lo checaré, hago entonces como si lo creará y luego reescribo la carpeta, gracias